# Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException:

Tags: intellij-idea

**The problem below occured on my Intellij**

```
Error:Internal error: (com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException) PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\Steven\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\compile-server\fraudserver_2012620e\out-target\data
com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException: PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users\Steven\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\compile-server\fraudserver_2012620e\out-target\data
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.getNonnegativeValue(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap$5.onDropFromCache(PersistentHashMap.java:233)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap$5.onDropFromCache(PersistentHashMap.java:219)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.SLRUMap.clear(SLRUMap.java:153)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doClose(PersistentHashMap.java:650)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.close(PersistentHashMap.java:641)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.close(AbstractStateStorage.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildDataManager.close(BuildDataManager.java:253)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.ProjectDescriptor.release(ProjectDescriptor.java:143)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.saveData(BuildSession.java:337)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:298)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index corrupted
    at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.hashIndex(IntToIntBtree.java:1101)
    at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.search(IntToIntBtree.java:400)
    at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.locate(IntToIntBtree.java:987)
    at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreeIndexNodeView.access$000(IntToIntBtree.java:383)
    at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.get(IntToIntBtree.java:181)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.getNonnegativeValue(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:312)
    ... 18 more
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 28):

Use File | Invalidate Caches and restart.

Comment: Mind you, this will also delete your local history, so if you want to play it safe, follow the file deletion root described below.

Comment: Didn't work for me in 2022.2.4, had to also rebuild the project.

Answer (score 24):

step 1 :File>Invalidate Caches/Restart

**step 2 :Build>Rebuild Project**

Answer (score 16):

1. Close IntelliJ
2. Wait a bit
3. Delete `C:\Users\USERNAME\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system` directory
4. Start IntelliJ
5. Rebuild project.

Source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/1110610?page=1

Comment: Because the OP didn't choose the answer that has worked for him, This worked for me instead of the most voted answer

Comment: Note: in recent versions the path is %LocalAppData%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\compile-server

Answer (score 10):

Delete the culprit file, in your case 
`C:\Users\Steven\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\compile-server\fraudserver_2012620e\out-target\data`
, or its parent directory, 
`C:\Users\Steven\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\compile-server\fraudserver_2012620e\out-target\`
, and all should be good again.

Don't forget to close IJ before deletion.

Answer (score 3):

Invalidate cache and rebuild didn't work. Delete C:\Users\USERNAME.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system directory and restart worked.

Answer (score 2):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition):

1. Select File
2. Invalidate Caches
3. Uncheck all options except "Clear downloaded shared indexes"
4. Click the "Invalidate and Restart" button
5. Wait for the IDE to restart and the indexes to reload

This will resolve the corrupted index, the downside is a few minutes to wait until the project is re-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Delete that file

`C:\Users\Steven\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\compile-server\fraudserver_2012620e\out-target\data`

And Invalidate/ Restart the Android studio

This helped me

Answer (score 1):

Complete steps to resolve this.

- first try android studio > file > invalidate cache/restart>invalidate only
- if that doesn't work try invalidate and restart
- if you still face the issue, delete temp files in directory below and re run project. The cache is recreated and this fixes it if everything fails.

`/Users/xx/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/compile-server/*`

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate caches and restart didn't work for me.
Locate and delete the file under build package

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by insufficient space. if the above answers don't work, try to clean your storage and then re-follow the above answers.

This has solved the problem for me after several tries of the above.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue just click on **Rebuild Project**.

**Build -> Rebuild Project**.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue just
**Restart your Project or Rebuild Project**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**nothing worked for me.**
i was here as this error "CorruptedException:" occurred with android studio
lastly
**i deleted (actually renamed)**
**"C:\Users\mns\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3"**

in "IntelliJIdea IDE" it will be:
**"C:\Users\mns\AppData\Local\Google\IntelliJIdea____._"**